# How to read string as XML with QDomDocument object in QT

Tags: c++, xml, qt, format, qstring

I am receiving string as a XML document with this function:

```
void HttpWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
     QString data = reply->readAll().trimmed();
     bool value=document->setContent(&data);
}
```

and here is my slot and signal:

```
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

When I put above code I get error that there is not pre-defined function that receive one string as I have sended...Can somone try to correct this so I can see how to put this Qstring value into xml document. So I can read XML

Thank you

EDIT:
these are the functions that I have to choose, I have tried all but it seems I am not sending right paremeters:

```
 // Qt extensions
    bool setContent(const QByteArray& text, bool namespaceProcessing, QString *errorMsg=0, int *errorLine=0, int *errorColumn=0 );
    bool setContent(const QString& text, bool namespaceProcessing, QString *errorMsg=0, int *errorLine=0, int *errorColumn=0 );
    bool setContent(QIODevice* dev, bool namespaceProcessing, QString *errorMsg=0, int *errorLine=0, int *errorColumn=0 );
    bool setContent(QXmlInputSource *source, bool namespaceProcessing, QString *errorMsg=0, int *errorLine=0, int *errorColumn=0 );
    bool setContent(const QByteArray& text, QString *errorMsg=0, int *errorLine=0, int *errorColumn=0 );
    bool setContent(const QString& text, QString *errorMsg=0, int *errorLine=0, int *errorColumn=0 );
    bool setContent(QIODevice* dev, QString *errorMsg=0, int *errorLine=0, int *errorColumn=0 );
    bool setContent(QXmlInputSource *source, QXmlReader *reader, QString *errorMsg=0, int *errorLine=0, int *errorColumn=0 );
```

EDIT 2:
I can't compile it, I can give you this code:

```
httpwindow.cpp: In member function 'void HttpWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)':
httpwindow.cpp:140: error: no matching function for call to 'QDomDocument::setContent(QString*)'
..\..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\include/QtXml/qdom.h:343: note: candidates are: bool QDomDocument::setContent(const QByteArray&, bool, QString*, int*, int*)
..\..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\include/QtXml/qdom.h:344: note:                 bool QDomDocument::setContent(const QString&, bool, QString*, int*, int*)
..\..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\include/QtXml/qdom.h:345: note:                 bool QDomDocument::setContent(QIODevice*, bool, QString*, int*, int*)
..\..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\include/QtXml/qdom.h:346: note:                 bool QDomDocument::setContent(QXmlInputSource*, bool, QString*, int*, int*)
..\..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\include/QtXml/qdom.h:347: note:                 bool QDomDocument::setContent(const QByteArray&, QString*, int*, int*)
..\..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\include/QtXml/qdom.h:348: note:                 bool QDomDocument::setContent(const QString&, QString*, int*, int*)
..\..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\include/QtXml/qdom.h:349: note:                 bool QDomDocument::setContent(QIODevice*, QString*, int*, int*)
..\..\..\..\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\include/QtXml/qdom.h:350: note:                 bool QDomDocument::setContent(QXmlInputSource*, QXmlReader*, QString*, int*, int*)
```

Or tell me what to do to get that Qdebug output. You mean like `Qdebug<<data` ?

Comment: can you post debug output for "data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed no overload of QDomDocument::setContent() which takes a QString pointer, passing by value would fix the error.

However there is another serious issue in your code which is that you are trying to convert from a QByteArray (the result of readAll()) to a QString.  This is not only unnecessary but dangerous, since the conversion is done assuming the content is ascii.  You can just call document->setContent(reply).

Comment: `document->setContent(reply)` doesn't seems to work. I get error: ** error: request for member 'setContent' in '((HttpWindow*)this)->HttpWindow::document', which is of non-class type 'QDomDocument*'** and this is my declaration of QDomDocument in .h file : `QDomDocument *document;`

Comment: This looks like you don't have an include for QDomDocument, but it's hard to say for sure without your complete code.

Comment: Try with QDomDocument document; (no pointer). No need to create QDom objects on the heap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Problem was that reference was not correctly placed.. needed to add `QT += XML`